# Checkbox size makes other elements drop under the line

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a form group, it contains of an input field with an addon, a checkbox with an image and a button next to them, they're displayed next to each other, but when i give my checkbox height and width the image and the button move down i don't know why, how can i fix that? here is my code:

```css
.box{
height: 34px;
width: 34px;
}

.btn-default{
height: 34px;
width: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/34x34"><input type="checkbox" class="box">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">+</button>
</div>
<div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grid system to easily manage your layout 
Please check below example

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
 input.checkbox-input{height: 34px;width: 34px;margin-top: 0;}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
     <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/34x34">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
      <button class="btn" value="+">+</button>
     </div>
                   <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you but how can i put the input field next to them?

Comment: @stephjhonny Edited please have look